# Cannot login or leave shared Azure tenant - not receiving ms authenticator notification

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, authenticator

After resetting my phone and the MS Authenticator setup for me@main.com (example address/domain) I lost access to a shared organization (me-guid@shared.com) and when trying to access that shared organization Azure account, MS Authenticator requests seems to be being sent to an old me@main.com MS authenticator setup, but are never received.

I'm able to see the shared organization in https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations but the same happens when I try to leave it in an attempt to solve this problem. That is, a notification is sent to me@main.com but never received.

Also every time I log to Azure it directly tries to log in to the shared organization, no way of logging in to the main organization (Maybe this is due to not having an Azure a licence in the main organization).

Shared.com Azure admin, have reset my membership and when I tried to login the app consent dialog showed up. After confirming it, a MS Authenticator dialog shows up, pointing to me@main.com, but it's notification seems to being sent to the old MS Authenticator setup, not the new one.

I think that the MS Authenticator dialog showing up when I access the shared tenant is pointing to an old registration inside that shared tenant and incorrectly showing my main email (used to show an auto generated collaboration email) I need to be able to get a new QR code for doing a new MS Authenticator setup in the shared tenant.